# Antd is not re-rendering the tags in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, antd

I have a component in reactjs which closes the tag and removes that particular value from the array and show rest of the unclosed tags.
Here's the code for it:

```
 const onHandleCloseTags = (e) => {
    // event for onClose for Tags
    var array = [...tags]; // make a separate copy of the array
    var index = array.indexOf(e);
    if (index !== -1) {
      array.splice(index, 1);
      console.log("slicing: ",array);
      setTags(array);
    }
}

return(
<>
                 {tags.map((e, index) => (
                      <Tag
                        closable
                        key={index}
                        onClose={() => onHandleCloseTags(e)}
                      >
                        {e}
                        {console.count("re-rendering")}
                      </Tag>
                    ))}

</>
)
```

If I have these items in `tags` useState : ['apple','mango'] and closes the `apple` tag, it automatically also closes the `mango` tag (more technically antd is making the display of `mango` tag as hidden).

So how can I overcome this issue? any ideas?

Tried to create separate copy for array but still not working

Comment: Please create a sandbox example
so that we can find the issue

Comment: what about trying e.preventDefault() before calling the delete code

Answer (score 0):

Try `findIndex` instead of `indexOf` , so your function should look like this :

```
const onHandleCloseTags = (e) => {
  var array = [...tags];
  var index = array.findIndex(
    (item) => item === e
  );
  if (index !== -1) {
    array.splice(index, 1);
    console.log("slicing: ",array);
    setTags(array);
   }
 }
```